# Gradient from clear to white

Tags: swiftui, navbar, gradient

I want to do an navbar like this -> [image]

But when I try to do it i have a shadow box and i can't resolve it -> [image].

```
HStack {
    Spacer()
    FriendsButtonView(index: $index).frame(width: width/5, height: width/5)
    Spacer()
    FloatingButtonView(index: $index, open: $openModal).frame(width: width/5, height: width/5)
    Spacer()
    faqButtonView(index: $index).frame(width: width/5, height: width/5)
    Spacer()
}.frame(width: width, height: height/10)
.background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.clear, Color.white]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
.clipped()
.offset(y: height/2.225)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a demo of possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoGradientHeaderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .shadow(radius: 10)
            Text("What is the role of ambassador?").font(.largeTitle)
        }
        .overlay(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.white.opacity(0.01), Color.white]),
            startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        .frame(height: 160)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but the problem with the overlay it's make impossible to click on the button, but i'm trying to work with the gradient parameters

Comment: Might be worth adding an explanation about why this is different. `UIColor.clear` has RGBA values of `0, 0, 0, 0` i.e. it is BLACK with 0 opacity. So when sliding along the gradient it will go through... `0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1` and `0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5` before getting to `1, 1, 1, 1`. And so will go from clear, to transparent grey, to white. Whereas your solution starts at WHITE with 0 opacity and so doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: @sett_gekz, you should add buttons *above* this header view, ie. into external ZStack, or another overlay

Answer (score 4):

Using help of @Asperi.

```
ZStack {
    VStack (spacing: 0) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.white.opacity(0.01), Color.white.opacity(1)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.white)
    }
    .frame(width: width, height: height/10)

    HStack {
        Spacer()
        MoneyButtonView(index: $index)
            .frame(width: width/5, height: width/5)
        Spacer()
        HomeButtonView(index: $index)
            .frame(width: width/5, height: width/5)
        Spacer()
        PoolButtonView(index: $index)
            .frame(width: width/5, height: width/5)
        Spacer()
    }
}
.offset(y: height/2.225)
.frame(width: width, height: height/10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to reiterate what @Fogmeister said in a comment:
The reason why the gradient from `Color.clear` to `Color.white` has a gray color, is that `Color.clear` is the same as `Color.black.opacity(0)`. And even though `Color.black.opacity(0)` and `Color.white.opacity(0)` look the same (they're both transparent), the interpolated colors will be different depending on which one you choose.